# aclocal version problem on Mac OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, autoconf

I am trying to compile an open source program on Mac OSX and getting stuck trying to get the build configured. I have autoconf version 2.63 installed but trying to do reconfigure I get this error "aclocal.m4:14: error: this file was generated for autoconf 2.61." and "you should regenerate the build system entirely".

I researched this as best I could and most seemed to imply automake should be able to regenerate itself using the autoreconf command. Autoreconf fails as well with the exact same message.

Things I've tried: remaking and reinstalling the autoconf package, remaking and reinstalling the m4 package, running the above commands as root instead of as a user.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
  - Mike

Answer (score 0):

Look for script like autogen.sh, they usually contain the right order of tools to run.

In this case the problem seems to be aclocal